# Problem on Convergence of a Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does this series diverge?
I know it doesn't make sense to split them.
I know both are divergent, but I don't know how to test the difference of two divergent series.
$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Do I combine them as one and go from there like this?

$$\sum_{n=1}^n \frac{\sqrt{n}-n}{n^{1.5}}$$

Comment: The second term "diverges faster" than the first, they don't compensate each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the general element of the series' sequence (multiplied by $\;(-1)\;$ in order to make it a positive series) and use the limit comparison test:

$$\frac{\frac{n-\sqrt n}{n\sqrt n}}{\frac1{\sqrt n}}=\frac{n-\sqrt n}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

and there you get your series divergence (fill in details)

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto Don Antonio's argument here. The intuitive point is that as n gets large 
$$
\dfrac{1}{n} << \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$ 
and so you are effectively just summing 
$$
-\sum{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}
$$
which you know diverges